# JUnit 5 How to get the instance of parent test form a nested test class

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I am implementing a [Mockito extension for JUnit 5](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/1221). Assume we are in a nested test and want to create mocks for the parent test class.

```
class RootTest{
  @Mock Foo mock;

  @Nested
  class NestedTest{
    @Test
    public void foo(){
       mock.bar();
    }
  }
}
```

To do that we need the instance of the `RootTest` in order to assign the mocks to the fields annotated with `@Mock`.
The current problem is to obtain the instance of the `RootTest` class. The first attempt was to get it via `ExtensionContext.getParent()` and `ExtensionContext.getTestInstance()` but the test instance is `null` for the parent.

Q: How to get the parent instance of the nested class? Reflection might help but is not an option, cause it is compiler dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer test instance is not accessible via `ExtensionContext`. However, if you let your extension implement `TestInstancePostProcessor`, it will be called for the outer and the inner test instance. In fact, it is meant to set instance variables (see our [sample Mockito extension](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/b048b807ef275c901bb73d3003e78f15c1803063/junit5-mockito-extension/src/main/java/com/example/mockito/MockitoExtension.java) for an example).

Comment: It works! The code is now more complex since I still need to implement `BeforeEachCallback` to process additional annotations to define the mockito-strictness. Is there a chance that `getTestInstance()` returns an test instance for a parent `ExtensionContext` in a future release?

Comment: The parent of the `ExtensionContext` represents the nested test class in your example and will only have a test instance set if you use `Lifecycle.PER_CLASS`. However, in that case it will contain an instance of the nested class which isn’t what you need. We could add another method to `ExtensionContext` to get all enclosing instances, or the enclosing instance for a given class literal. Can you please create a GitHub issue for it so we can continue the discussion there?